# Run-time error '424': Object Required IE.Document.GetElementById

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to auto-complete a form on a website with values of an excel file.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
.Visible = True
.navigate "https://www.ryanair.com/be/nl/check-in"
End With

Do Until IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

   IE.document.getElementbyid("username").Value = "resa@connections.be"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a timed loop for element to be present

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
'
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, t As Date, ele As Object
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10


    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.ryanair.com/be/nl/check-in"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .document.getElementById("username")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While ele Is Nothing

        If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        ele.Value = "resa@connections.be"

        Stop
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the quick answer!  I just made small changes, as I received an error and I work with a button.  It works like a charm now!

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, t As Date, ele As Object
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    t = Timer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.ryanair.com/be/nl/check-in"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .document.getElementById("username")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While ele Is Nothing

        If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        ele.Value = "resa@connections.be"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hiya, What error did you receive? And on which line please?  I tested it and it ran fine. As far as I can see you have simply put this inside a click event which I admit I did miss (my bad!)  You need .Quit otherwise you will eventually run out of memory. Also, you need t = timer just before the Do. See my answer. In my answer you would remove the stop line.

Comment: Sounds good that you made a small change for that script to work @Merijn. But, which script you considered as a model to reach the conclusion? Try accepting the answer provided by QHarr. Thanks.