# Excel VBA to Click a button in Webpage to download a file and email it to a list of emails

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-scraping

The HTML code looks like this. The button says "Open in Excel" that needs to be clicked. Once clicked, it downloads a csv file.

```
<div class="analyze-view-nav-bar"><div class="analyze-view-nav-bar-left-button-container"><button title="View results" class="analyze-view-nav-button office-form-theme-button button-control light-background-button"><div class="button-content">View results</div></button></div><div class="analyze-view-export-to-excel-button"><div><button title="Open in Excel" class="analyze-view-export-button-container glyph-button-control-horizontal button-control light-background-button" aria-label="Open in Excel"><div class="button-content"><i class="ms-Icon ms-Icon--ExcelLogo forms-icon-size24x24" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="analyze-view-export-button-label">Open in Excel</span></div></button></div></div></div>
```

this is the VBA

```
Sub test()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim frm As HTMLFrameElement
Dim frms As HTMLElementCollection
Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "https://forms.office.com/Pages/DesignPage.aspx#Analysis=true&FormId=AY3zc5go1USqcDdJLNPiTh0SDUMn3HlMvKv7KoZTC9VUN1FIWUtSREM3RVFUQjRTWUczMlNPM09CTC4u&Token=be26006342a64df49e7dafb25915c140"

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate strSQL

        Do Until .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
        'Set doc = IE.document

        ie.document.all("Open in Excel").Click



    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [ask] and how to provide a [example].

Comment: Ok, but... what's the question? Please share us the [code](/help/mwe), what you've tried, and describe the problem

Comment: your code, any error message and which line, the relevant html using snippet tool via [edit] and ideally the url.

Comment: does it require login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector (assuming not in parent iframe/frame. You can thus target the button by its `title` attribute value. Otherwise, you need to negotiate the parent iframe/frame.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[title='Open in Excel']").click
```

Use a proper page load wait as well

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

Comment: It loads the web page, but doesn't click. It shows an error.

I am doing this now:

   While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        
        ie.document.querySelector("[title='Open in Excel']").Click

Comment: it's a runtime error and the line is ie.document.querySelector("[title='Open in Excel']").click

Comment: try stepping through code line by line with F8 to ensure page loaded - does it still error?

Comment: I did it. It doesn't show an error. It does click. Not sure why it doesn't do it all at once. The purpose was to fully download the excel file and email it to a group.

Comment: so it is because the attempt to click happens before the element is ready. You can use a [timed loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55494738/6241235) waiting for item to be present.

Comment: We are already having it wait:
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
ie.document.querySelector("[title='Open in Excel']").Click

Comment: Now I have it like this:
  While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        
        ie.document.querySelector("[title='Open in Excel']").Click

Comment: This one works:
  While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        
        ie.document.querySelector("[title='Open in Excel']").Click
        
        While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend

I think this is what you meant. I appreciate your help! Do you know how to click on Open and email that downloaded file?

Comment: you would need to look at existing answers on SO. There are answers for interacting with 1) the save/open file dialog Internet Explorer; 2) Adding a reference to Microsoft Outlook and then using it's mailItem functionality to do mailing