# I want to reference specific text in a website, copy it, and paste to excel

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I've written VBA code to open IE, enter a specific query based on excel data, and I now want to copy a specific piece of text to paste back in excel, then repeat for 15000 rows.

This VBA code works to open IE and perform the search

```
Sub SearchBot()

    'dimension (declare or set aside memory for) our variables
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 'special object variable representing the IE browser
    Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element
    Dim y As Integer 'integer variable we'll use as a counter
    Dim result As String 'string variable that will hold our result link

    'initiating a new instance of Internet Explorer and asigning it to objIE
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    'make IE browser visible (False would allow IE to run in the background)
    objIE.Visible = True

    'navigate IE to this web page 
    objIE.navigate "https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/hcpf/find-doctor"


    'wait here a few seconds while the browser is busy
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'in the Location put cell F2 (Zip Code) in "Find Providers Near Me"
    objIE.document.getElementById("search_address").Value = _
      Sheets("All Bx Providers").Range("F2").Value

    'in the Within put "10"
    'objIE.document.getElementById("search_radius").Value = _
     ' "10"

    'in the Name put cell "B2" (Last Name) in "Find Providers by Name"
    objIE.document.getElementById("text_search").Value = _
      Sheets("All Bx Providers").Range("B2").Value


    'click the 'go' button
    objIE.document.getElementById("search").Click

    'wait again for the browser
    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

now I need to pull from this site:

> https://www.healthfirstcolorado.com/find-doctors/#/container-fluid?address=81101%20United%20States&radius=8050

This code:

```
<div id="results_list" style="height: 445px; overflow: hidden scroll; display: block;"><div class="span12"><p class="row-fluid item-list" style="margin: 0; font-size: 110%;"><strong>Cotter, Carol</strong></p>
```

I need to copy Cotter, Carol and paste it to cell N2.

Then make my macro repeat this by searching F3 and B3 and pasting the correct value to N3, and so on...

I get errors such as "needs an object".

I can't navigate .getElementbyClassName or any similar queries.

Comment: Can there be more than one result per search?

Comment: Also after the click you likely need another wait e.g. _Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop_  or even a [timed loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55494738/6241235) for element to be present.  And the class name  you can use is _item-list_ (1 of the two classes as the element's class is multivalued) as in ie.document.querySelector(".item-list") or ie.document.querySelectorAll(".item-list")

Comment: Could loop thru elementid's and search for results_list.. once found get the .innertext