# Wait for Web Page to Finish Loading

Tags: vba, automation, webautomation

I have some web automation that works just fine. But, I am looking for a cleaner way, if it exists, to pause the processing until the web page gets done building.

I see how others use 
`Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop` 
or 
`Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop`.

Both of these do NOT seem to work every time the code runs. It seems that if the Web is slow it messes up. These commands have been "hit and miss" for me.

I have added the 
`Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))` 
before the Loops and that seems to be working for now.

Is there any command that is fool proof and will really pause the code processing until the web pages are fully loaded no matter what the internet speed? Is it my code that is the problem?

```
Sub Test()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Element As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True

    'Navagate To Website
    IE.navigate "https://www.website.com/"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    IE.document.getElementById("ElementName1").Focus

    'SignOn Website
    IE.document.getElementById("ElementName1").Value = "UserID"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    IE.document.getElementById("ElementName2").Value = "Password"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    IE.document.getElementById("ElementName2").Click

    'Wait for next page ***************************************
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    '**********************************************************

    'Enter Patient Data On Website
    Dim pgTAGS As Object
    Dim pgTag As Object
    Set pgTAGS = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each pgTag In pgTAGS ' Loop through every input tag
    If pgTag.className = "chosen-search-input default" And _
            pgTag.Value = "Enter at least 3 Characters" Then
            pgTag.Focus
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            SendKeys "{1}{2}{3}", True
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
            SendKeys "{TAB}", True ' Seems to be required to exit dropdown list field
            Exit For
        End If
    Next pgTag

    'Member ID
    IE.document.getElementById("memberID").Value = "A99999999999"
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True

    'Date of Birth
    IE.document.getElementById("memberDOB").Value = "01/01/1977"
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True

    SendKeys "{TAB}", True

    'Date of Service: From
    IE.document.getElementById("memberFromDate").Value = "08/08/2008"
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True

    'Date of Service: To
    IE.document.getElementById("memberToDate").Value = "08/08/2008"
    SendKeys "{TAB}", True ' Seems to be required to highlight Search Claim button

    'BUTTON: Search Claims
    SendKeys "{ENTER}", True

    'Wait for next page ***************************************
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
    '**********************************************************

    'Sub Scrape Data From Website
    Dim t As Integer, r As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim elmCollection As Object
    IE.document.Focus

    Set elmCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")

    For t = 0 To (elmCollection.Length - 1)
        For r = 0 To (elmCollection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
            For c = 0 To (elmCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = _
                elmCollection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
            Next c
        Next r
    Next t

    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a timed loopwhich will allow a max wait time,  checking for presence of an element on the fully loaded page,  then potentially retry and/or gracefully abort code.

Comment: I will try this

Comment: Foe example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55494738/6241235

Comment: Well, I finally got back to working on my project and I testing your suggestion and it worked great! Thanks so much!

Comment: You are most welcome