# Web Scraper page navigation issue

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am using the following to scraper links from DUCKDUCKGO, it was working fine up until a week ago. It now no longer extracts if I have the page navigation active, if I comment this part of the code out then It will ONLY extract the first page.

For several days I have been trying a few methods of page navigation but nothing seems to work for me. I just can not work out what is wrong as the page Element ID is still the same as is using the "a" tag.

Could someone please advise where I am going wrong, as advised the it will extract the first page as long as I comment out the navigation part of the code.

```html
<div class="result result--more" id="rld-1">
  <a href="javascript:;" class="result--more__btn btn btn--full">More results</a>
</div>
```

```
Private Sub duckduckgoScraper()
'''DuckDuckGo URL SCRAPER
Dim ie As Object
Dim HTMLdoc As Object
Dim div As Object
Dim link As Object
Dim url As String
Dim i As Long
Dim myCounter As Long
Dim objMoreResults As Object
Dim p As Long

'''Takes seach from Sheet10 to DUCKDUCKGO
    url = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=" & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("G17").Value & Range("H17").Value, " ", "+")
On Error Resume Next
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
      .Visible = True
      .navigate url
      Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4 
      Loop
   End With

    Set HTMLdoc = ie.document

'''Searches URLS and places them in Sheet called Sheet2  ROW 2 Column A
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
      pageNumber = 1
      i = 2

    Do
     p = 1
     backP:

''''###########################################################
''''##########    This part is the Problem    #################
''''########################################################### 
  
   Set objMoreResults = ie.document.getElementById("rld-" & p)
    On Error GoTo 0
      'End do in NO MORE results
    If objMoreResults Is Nothing Then Exit Do

   If objMoreResults <> Sheet10.Range("I17").Value Then
      objMoreResults.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click
  
   Set objMoreResults = Nothing: p = p + 1
      'Scrolls Down the Browser
     ie.document.parentWindow.Scroll 0&, 99999
   Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set HTMLdoc = ie.document
''''#######################################################
''''##########     End of Problem     #####################
''''#######################################################

''' extract urls
    For Each div In HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("div")
        If div.getAttribute("class") = "result__body links_main links_deep" Then
            Set link = div.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = link.getAttribute("href")
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next div

''' Loop Counter
    myCounter = myCounter + 1
    Worksheets("Sheet10").Range("G6").Value = myCounter

   GoTo backP
   End If

Loop
End With

ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
    Set HTMLdoc = Nothing
    Set objMoreResults = Nothing
    Set div = Nothing
    Set link = Nothing

End Sub
```

As always thanks in advance

Comment: You need a timed loop for that id to be present. Apart from that, you should be explicit about what error messages you get and exactly which line(s) throws them (and remove that On Error Resume Next block.... IMO, those should only be used as close as possible to the potential source of error, and only as part of a planned strategy e.g. where an element may sometimes be present for one result but not for another.)

Comment: QHarr thanks for the update, I tested the same code today on the same PC & it worked just fine. Extracted data no problem. I changed NOTHING, yet it would not extract data for a week. In addition have taken your advice & removed "On Error Resume Next" works fine with or without this line off code. Not sure what the error was. I also did not get an error message so could not pinpoint what line had the error. All I knew was that it would NOT extract if the page navigation code was active, if i was to comment this out it worked, hence highlight the block of code as the problem area. Thanks again

Comment: It works sometimes because page loads faster. See my comment about a timed loop waiting for id to be present. See example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55494738/6241235)